# runAction CCSprite drawn with CCRenderTexture

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I needed to have CCSprite masked and I used CCRenderTexture for drawing sprites with that feature. It works fine but now I'am trying to animate those sprites but I would like to use runAction CCNode method for more complex animation:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.png"];

self.rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:980 height:726 pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
self.rtx.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
[self addChild:self.rtx];

[self drawTexture:0];
[self schedule:@selector(drawTexture:) interval:0.1];

-(void)drawTexture:(ccTime)delta_{
    [self.rtx beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
    [sprite visit];
    [self.rtx end];
}
```

So I would like update its position for example:

```
[sprite runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10.0 position:CGPointMake(0, sprite.position.y + 1)]];
```

The problem is that I don't know if its possible and if it is where doing the update

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wan't to call methods only available in the CCSprite class?
Then use the CCSprite class ;).

You can convert a **CCRenderTexture to a CCSprite** with:

```
CCSprite *spriteFromRTX = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
spriteFromRTX.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
```

don't forget to set the position of the sprite, because it doesn't take the position from the renderTexture.

Also beware of the problem, that the the CCSprite may have flipped Y Axis.

But you can use `flipY = YES` on the resulting sprite, see: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

As the comments mentioned in CCTexture2D.h:

/** CCTexture2D class.

- This class allows to easily create OpenGL 2D textures from images, text or raw data.
- The created CCTexture2D object will always have power-of-two dimensions.
- Depending on how you create the CCTexture2D object, the actual image area of the texture might be smaller than the texture dimensions i.e. “contentSize” != (pixelsWide, pixelsHigh) and (maxS, maxT) != (1.0, 1.0).
- Be aware that the content of the generated textures will be upside-down!

*/